# Combined `host` and `link` networking in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tcpdump, docker-network

The scenario is to build a `watcher` container that is able to listen to any network traffic on a given `docker-compose` combination of services. Besides that I has to be possible that `watcher` directly sends packets to dedicated services.

I found that `host` networking on `watcher` is basically what I was looking for (including the implications of possibly having too much information in terms of all network devices managed by the Docker engine). In order to directly target communication to any services it seems to be required to use `link` settings - which contradicts `host` networking.

#### Current `docker-compose.yaml`

(complete configuration available at https://github.com/ohader/docker-watcher-demo)

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  watcher:
    build:
      context: ./custom
    network_mode: host
    entrypoint: "tcpdump -i any"

  first:
    build:
      context: ./custom
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.0.11
    entrypoint: "sleep infinity"

  second:
    build:
      context: ./custom
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.0.22
    entrypoint: "ping first"

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.25.0.0/16"
```

Basically the `second` service is pinging `first` service. The `watcher` is able to monitor that by using `network_mode: host`.
Since e.g. `ping first` is not possible from within `watcher`, according IP addresses have been hardcoded, thus `watcher` is using e.g. `ping 172.25.0.11` instead.

#### Questions

- Is there a better way for having "physical" access to all packages that are send to dynamically composed network bridges `br-*` using `tcpdump` (currently achieved by using `host` networking)?
- Is there a way to combine the features of `host` and `bridge` networking, e.g. also by using different drivers of even a custom plugin? I looked into drivers `macvlan` and `ipvlan` (L2, experimental feature on
  Docker) but failed to be able to monitor traffic across all composed services.

Thanks in advance for any feedback or hint. I looked into service discovery (consul, etcd) using `overlay` networking, which felt a little bit too much for my scenario (not using most of those features).

Comment: Ipvlan is coming out of experimental in 19.03 (currently in beta).

Comment: This is an old question, but I provide this for reference. You wanna try my little docker-bridgenw-dump utility, which automates tcpdump for bridge network traffic. https://github.com/gprossliner/docker-bridgenw-dump
https://hub.docker.com/r/gprossliner/docker-bridgenw-dump

Comment: I still did not find a solution with Docker - thus, thanks for that late reply. In the end I'd like to simulate Botnet attacks on a docker network with locking fake TCP packages being routed to the real/public network and leave the host (e.g. see https://github.com/ohader/typo3v9-hack/blob/master/.ddev/attack/entrypoint.sh).
I'll play around a little bit with your solution and using Docker client in a container for that...